# How to structure page folders in Ionic in the best way?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm looking for a better way to organize the pages on Ionic, pages related to a subject, such as products, what do we have in products? Edit, register, list, details, what would the structure look like?

```
 product-edit
 product-list
 product-details
 product-add
```

Or maybe this way?

```
product
   edit
   add
   details
   list
```

I do not know if these are the best options, can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the second one:

```
product
   edit
   add
   details
   list
```

This is absolutly fine. You have a better overview on which pages a important for products than in the first example.